# Optimal block size for spatial bootstrapping

Tags: references, bootstrap, heteroscedasticity, spatial, resampling

Take a regression model:
$$
y_s = X_s\beta + \epsilon
$$

Where $E[\epsilon|X] = 0$, but $cor(\epsilon_s, \epsilon_{near}) > cor(\epsilon_s, \epsilon_{far})> 0$.

In other words, $X$ is uncorrelated with the noise, but the noise isn't random.

Furthermore, $X$ is also spatially autocorrelated.

The goal is unbiased causal inference on $\beta$, with confidence intervals that achieve nominal coverage levels.

Given this setup, there will be some confounding between the signal and the noise in space, just by chance.  Given that it is random, OLS estimates of $\hat\beta$ will still be unbiased, but standard errors assuming IID data will be too small (or maybe too big, sometimes?).  I suppose this is a form of heteroskedasticity.

Analytic methods for assessing consistent parameter covariance matrices exist.  For example, [here](http://www.fight-entropy.com/2010/06/standard-error-adjustment-ols-for.html).

But what about bootstrap methods?  [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300415000904?via%3Dihub#bib18) uses a spatial block bootstrap, using k-means as the block.  But their choice of the number of clusters seems ad-hoc.  [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611261) is concerned with selection of block size for spatial block bootstraps, but in their setup they consider spatial autoregressive models, and I'm not sure that their work applies to my simpler case.

Can anyone point me towards valid resampling methods for spatially-dependent data?  Ideally that'll provide some guidance on how to select the number (and shape?) of blocks?